# vSphere Host - periodic spike

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Since last two days, one of my vSphere host server is showing periodic CPU load spike as shown in the following diagram. The day before the issue started, the vSphere client lost connection to this host server while all of it's VMs were running fine. The connection somehow came back to normal. The issue could be related to a single VM which in this case a Zeus load balancer. I have noticed that the same issue appears to another host if that VM is migrated to it.

[image]

To be honest, the same symptom can be seen on every other Chart Options i.e Datastore, Disk, Memory, System etc. So, the issue is not CPU related,

I would be pleased if someone could help.

Comment: It's likely your Zeus ZXTM load balancer. Log in and see what it's doing at the given time.

Comment: We're a big user of ZXTM/STM/Steelhead - given you call it ZXTM does that mean you've not upgraded for a while as the name has changed a few times - if not perhaps try an update?

Comment: I have checked Zeus, the CPU load average remains pretty low. And yes, my ZXTM version 7.4 is probably quite old. The issue started a sometime after I created a new pool on zxtm. So, now I have reverted that change. I will keep an eye. Is there anything inside the vSphere that I can check?